Fedora 40 headphones do not work in applications, even though they "work" when tested in system utilities
I am running Fedora 40 with KDE 6.1.4 (Wayland) on an ASUS ROG Strix G733P laptop  with an NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4080.  Everything runs great except...
I can't get my headphones to work.
The internal speakers work fine.
When I plug in the headphones,  go to "System Settings -> Sound" and choose "Headphones -> Analog Serial Duplex," it tests fine -- I hear the voice saying "Front Left" and "Front Right" loud and clear in the headphones.
However, none of my browsers (Brave, Tor,  and Firefox) will push sound through the headphones using YouTube, Amazon, etc., and neither will mplayer when I play an mp3 file.  All work fine when the headphones are unplugged and playing through the speakers.
Some stuff:
% sudo lspci -k | grep [Aa]udio
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation AD104 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
08:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] ACP/ACP3X/ACP6x Audio Coprocessor (rev 62)
08:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller

% sudo dnf list alsa-firmware   
Last metadata expiration check: 0:46:23 ago on Wed 11 Sep 2024 07:19:15 PM EDT.
Installed Packages
alsa-firmware.noarch                                                                1.2.4-12.fc40

% sudo alsa-info.sh --no-upload
cat: /tmp/alsa-info.jOQHPp0gSe/sdwstatus.tmp: No such file or directory
alsactl: get_control:255: Cannot read control '2,0,0,L0 DSP1 Prot f20b EVENTS,0': Device or resource busy
cat: /tmp/alsa-info.jOQHPp0gSe/alsactl.tmp: No such file or directory 

% sudo cat  alsa-info.txt.mzlMGnznPI
Too long to copy and paste, and I don't know what's important, but
here's the headphone parts:

| grep phone
  Control: name="Headphone Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="Headphone Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
Simple mixer control 'Headphone',0
[   29.209313] input: HD-Audio Generic Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:08:00.6/sound/card1/input26

Also:
Alsamixer appropriately turns off speakers and turns on headphone bars when I plug in the headphone.  Auto mute is disabled.

A followup.  This seems to be a fedora issue.  I just installed kubuntu 24.04 on the laptop and the headphones work fine.
